# Providing login/password to svn in a safer manner

Tags: unix, svn

I have a Unix-based webtool which performs svn operations. The account the tool is running under does not have any svn permissions (nor should it, different users have different permissions in svn).

Instead, users enter svn username and password in the web page. Than the webtool runs external svn by the means of external process call with `--username` and `--password`. Since the tool can run quite a long-running svn commands, username and password are visible to everybody having physical access to the server for a long time with a simple `ps` command. And this an apparent issue.

Is there something which can be done to alleviate it? It's a corporate environment, so it doesn't have to be airtight. For example, if I could limit the time when username and password are visible (say, by running a process which runs really quick) that would be OK. Ideal case would be to run svn with input redirection - but I couldn't force svn to accept password from stdin.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @LazyBadger, hmmm.... Not sure what my alleged nationality has to do with the question. On any rate, i believe, it will be more in SO spirit if you provide an answer in usual format )

Comment: Alleged?! Сережа, ну хоть мне мозги не трахай, да? По логину и профилю палишься во весь рост. А чат нужен, чтобы обсудить всякие мелкие детали, прочим не интересные и не важные, бо - хреново у тебя задан вопрос, сильно неполно. А напрягаться аглицкой мовой в двойном переводе мне сильно лениво

Comment: @LazyBadger, ok - how can I find you there?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104927/discussion-between-sergeya-and-lazybadger